# "" bundle because the bundle has not been loaded - Empty bundle name

Tags: cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I'm trying to load a nib, but keep getting the following error:

```
-[NSViewController initWithCoder:] could not instantiate an NSViewController for a nib in the "" bundle because the bundle has not been loaded.
```

The bundle name is missing...what would cause that?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem
{

    let item = collectionView.makeItemWithIdentifier("MyNib", forIndexPath: indexPath) // Crashes here

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you're using to instantiate the NSViewController...

Comment: Added the code, it's pretty standard stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

It was because the NibName and NibBundle were not set on the NSCollectionViewItem object.

Comment: I spent a couple hours on this issue, but now solved thanks to your answer!

Comment: What should be the Nib Bundle Identifier?